# Array object fails to initialize as array in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, initialization

I'm trying to create a class Song that takes in two inputs, song and artist, and creates objects that are arrays i.e. [song, artist]. When I run this code, my assertion that my object is an array fails. How can I correctly write an initialize method that takes in two inputs and creates an array object?

My code:

```
class Song 
    def initialize(song, artist)
        @piece = [song, artist]
    end
end

hello = Song.new("hello", "goodbye")

def assert
    raise "Assertion failed!" unless yield
end

assert { hello.kind_of?(Array) }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hello` is a `Song` object, not an array object. Do you mean `hello.piece` ?

```
class Song 
    attr_reader :piece  # <---------

    def initialize(song, artist)
        @piece = [song, artist]
    end
end

hello = Song.new("hello", "goodbye")

def assert
    raise "Assertion failed!" unless yield
end

assert { hello.piece.kind_of?(Array) } # <------
```

Comment: Thanks, this passes! But I'm still not sure if my object is initializing correctly - I feel like this assertion should pass, but maybe I'm formatting it wrong too because it fails: assert {Song.new("hello", "goodbye") == ["hello", "goodbye"]}

Answer (score 1):

your assertion assumes that `hello` is an `array` which is incorrect.  `hello` is an instance of the class `Song`.

However, if you did added this to the top of your class:

```
attr_reader :piece
```

and then did this

```
assert { hello.piece.kind_of?(Array) }
```

that would pass.